# Como fazer validação de checkbox no Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Eu estou estudando ruby on rails e pouco tempo, e um dos exercicios que estou tentando fazer é um checkbox e um botão submit em uma página haml, o objetivo é que o botão submit só funcione caso o checkbox esteja marcado, caso não apenas dê uma mensagem genérica como "Complete os campos", como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Rails tem um validador chamado `acceptance_of`. É utilizado quando você tem um booleano e quer verificar se esse valor é verdadeiro.

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: true
end
```

Veja mais validações do Rails na [documentação](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

Quando você chamar `model.save`, verifique o seguinte:

```
if person.save
  # successo!
else
  # erro :(
  person.errors.full_messages
  # => [ { terms_of_service: "must be accepted" }]
end
```

Comment: No botão do submit em si eu preciso passar o valor do acceptance? ou no checkbox? Só precisa do model e controller? Ainda não peguei muito bem o jeito do haml

Comment: @dfop02 no model